# How to remove all rows from a table except first two and last?

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I've seen a lot of questions about how to select all but the first and last rows of a table, but I want to know how to select everything except the first TWO rows and the last. Right now I have this to select all but the first two:

```
$("#sometable").find("tr:gt(1)").remove();
```

and I need some way to get the last one as well. Maybe some way to combine with

```
:not(:last)
```

?

I'm fairly new to jQuery and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20):

This is what you need:

```
$("#sometable").find('tr').slice(2,-1).remove()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQhQ3/)

[jsperf](http://jsperf.com/removingtablerows) of my and [@Evan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483349/evan-mulawski)'s solutions.

[image]

Comment: @cnhe by `slice` it's about 5 times faster,than by '`tr:gt(1):not(:last)`' selector.So prabably,for you using `slice` could be more convinient,than using selector.

Answer (score 12):

Just combine the selectors:

```
$("#sometable").find("tr:gt(1):not(:last)").remove();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqnQC/)

Comment: This is why I'm starting to love jquery: the answer is often so easy and intuitive. Thanks, it worked perfectly!

Comment: No problem. And you can almost always read these selectors as a sentence: "find all `tr` that are after the second (1+1, since its zero-based) child that are not the last child of its parent."